# Query based on previous and next values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table test1

```
-- auto-generated definition
CREATE TABLE test1
(
  imei     VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '1'             NULL,
  id       INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
  lat      FLOAT(10, 5)                        NOT NULL,
  lng      FLOAT(10, 5)                        NOT NULL,
  ign      CHAR                                NULL,
  datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

With following data

```
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 1, 27.1, 28.2, '0', '2018-04-18 02:15:25');
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 2, 27.2, 28.2, '1', '2018-04-18 02:16:59');
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 3, 27.3, 28.4, '1', '2018-04-18 02:17:59');
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 4, 27.4, 28.5, '0', '2018-04-18 02:18:59');
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 1, 27.1, 28.2, '0', '2018-04-18 02:25:25');
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 2, 27.2, 28.2, '1', '2018-04-18 02:26:59');
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 3, 27.3, 28.4, '1', '2018-04-18 02:27:59');
INSERT INTO test1 (imei, id, lat, lng, ign, datetime) VALUES ('1', 4, 27.4, 28.5, '0', '2018-04-18 02:28:59');
```

Logic is here:

1. First it will check for `ign` column; if the value is 1 (means ignition on) then it will generate this first part: `imei lat lng status datetime`
2. Then the query needs to pick the second part: it will check for `ign` column if the value is 0 (ignition off) then it will generate this second part: `imei lat lng status datetime`

I have tried this query

```
SELECT test1.imei, test1.lat, test1.lng ,
MAX(CASE WHEN test1.ign = 1 THEN 'ign on' END) as IgnOn,
min(CASE WHEN test1.ign = 0 THEN 'ign of' END) as IgnOff
FROM test1 GROUP BY test1.imei, test1.lat, test1.lng;
```

After many search I'm able create this query

```
select *,
  if(test1.ign = 1, 'ign on', 'ign off') as status,
  CASE
  WHEN test1.ign = 1 THEN @a := 0
    ELSE @a := 1
  END as mycondition
from test1
 WHERE test1.imei = 1
  HAVING test1.ign = @a
  ORDER BY reg_date ASC;
```

This is the result I need:

```
imei    i1lat    i1lng    i1status         i0datetime           i0lat    ign1lng    i1status    i1datetime
  1      27.2     28.2       1          2018-04-18 02:16:59      27.4      28.5       0         2018-04-18 02:18:59
  1      27.2     28.2       1          2018-04-18 02:26:59      27.4      28.5       0         2018-04-18 02:28:59
```

I can write a PHP script that will generate the data that I want, but I want to generate the same data using MySQL.

Comment: @MuhammadMemon Please post it in your question, it would get formatted and we can read it better.

Comment: i have updated my query can you guys please check that.

Comment: _"after many search i'm able create this query"_ And what is wrong with it? What, specifically, does it not do that you require?

Comment: yes some how, but that query is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
  if(test1.ign = 1, 'ign on', 'ign off') as status,
  CASE
  WHEN test1.ign = 1 THEN @a := 0
    ELSE @a := 1
  END as mycondition
from test1
 WHERE test1.imei = 1
  HAVING test1.ign = @a
  ORDER BY reg_date ASC;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.